# Access cookie and set Bearer token in prepareHeaders RTKQuery in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am making use of RTK query during SSR, the setup has been good so far, however, now I need to access endpoints that are protected using the Bearer Token.

The token is created and sent to the client upon login, I then make use of the `setCookie` function from the `nookies` package to set a cookie with the accessToken.
The problem now, is that I am finding it difficult to properly get the token in the Authorization header for endpoints that needs it during SSR, I have however been able to get the cookie in the prepareHeader function, through the store **thunk's extra** ... when I log the cookie to the console, the value of the cookie gets printed out in my terminal, however when I check the request headers on my browser, it says `Bearer undefined`

Here's my store.js

```js
export const makeStore = (context) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
      properties: propertiesSlice,
      filter: filterSlice,
      agent: agentSlice,
    },
    middleware: (gDM) =>
      gDM({
        thunk: {
          extraArgument: {
            context,
          },
        },
      }).concat(api.middleware),
  });
};
```

and here is my rootApi

```js
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { extra }) => {
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.set(
        "Authorization",
        `Bearer ${extra?.context?.req?.cookies?.accessToken}`
      );
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath];
    }
  },
  tagTypes: ["User", "Property"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```